# how can I solve font icon issue with cross browsing?

Tags: css, font-face

attach is the code I have made.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>campaign builder</title>
    <!-- Style sheets -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="square orange">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="icon-envelope">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
   font-size:12px;
   font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "untitled-font-5";
  src:url("fonts/untitled-font-5.eot");
  src:url("fonts/untitled-font-5.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("fonts/untitled-font-5.woff") format("woff"),
    url("fonts/untitled-font-5.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/untitled-font-5.svg#untitled-font-5") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}

[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: "untitled-font-5" !important;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "untitled-font-5" !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size:34px;
  color:#b7430f;
}

.icon-envelope:before {
  content: "a";
}


/* start css form square*/

.square {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 73px;
    height: 73px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:center;
}

.table {
    display:table;
    height: 100%;
}

.icon-envelope {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.alert {
    background: url(images/alert.png) center center no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:3px;
    right:0px;
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
}

.orange {
    border:4px solid #f17b1c;
}

/* end css form square*/
```

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107452929/code/index.html

there is an issue as the position of the icon looks of in ff and ie but not in chrome.

how can I manage it to be the same in all browsers?

thanks.

Comment: Any chance of an screen shot, I see it the same in all browsers...
Tested: FF Chrome IE9

Comment: Any reason why you would need to nest _four_ divs into another to display _one_ simple icon …?

Comment: its has noting to do with the issue...